# StateProvider generate template url dynamically - closure issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, url-routing

I'm generating my url states from an enum object by enumerating through the enum and generating a state for each value in it.

Now I need to generate my template url with a combination of a routing param and the current state and I seek a closure problem that I can't pass through.

This is my code:

```
// Stages is the enum
for (var stage in Stages) {
       $stateProvider.state(stage.toString(),
       {
           url: '/' + currStageStr + '/:param1',
           templateUrl:function ($stateParams) {
                 return getTemplateUrl($stateParams.param1, stage);
           },
           resolve: { model: getStageModel },
           controller: getController
        });
}
```

My problem is in this section:

```
templateUrl:function ($stateParams) {
                     return getTemplateUrl($stateParams.param1, stage);
            }
```

Since stage comes from the outside scope, I get the same value on each iteration - Closure issue.

I didn't find anything on the web that can give me a different function signature for generating a template url dynamically.

**I'm looking to do something like this:**

```
templateUrl:function ($stateParams,stage) {
                     return getTemplateUrl($stateParams.param1, stage);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around and create my own scope to avoid the closure issue:

```
for (var stage in Stages) {
    generateStageObj($stateProvider,stage)
}

 function generateStageObj($stateProvider, stage) {
            return $stateProvider.state(stage.toString(),
                {
                    url: '/' + currStageStr + '/:param1',
                    templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                        return getTemplateUrl($stateParams.param1, stage);
                    },
                    resolve: { model: getStageModel },
                    controller: getController
                });
        }
```